# CollectionView - creating groups via conditional not a property

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, collectionview

I could probably accomplish what I want in a less elegant way, but to avoid that, is it possible to:

With a single CollectionView, create a group within it based on some condition (eg, one of it's other properties not being null)? I could create a Property in the class that the view is based on, but this is a pretty specific/minor use case, so I'd prefer not to. Doesn't matter if I do this in WPF/XAML or in code.

I would then need to sort the items within the view by their group affiliation, as well as sorting items within the groups. But I'm mainly concerned about my first point.

Answer (score 0):

make your own class deriving from PropertyGroupDescription and override the NamesMatch method, implementing your own logic about which items to group.

in the following example i group all items of type MyClass, whose property OtherProperty is null:

.xaml

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding MyItems}" x:Key="myKey">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <local:MyGroupingDescription PropertyName="." />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

.cs

```
public class MyGroupingDescription : PropertyGroupDescription
{
    public override bool NamesMatch(object groupName, object itemName)
    {
        if((groupName as MyClass).OtherProperty == null && (itemName as MyClass).OtherProperty==null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```